# Artifactory Cross-Replication

Tags: artifactory

Caveat: I'm an IT guy, not a JAVA programmer. So please use small words. :)

I have two Artifactory servers, with more on the way for remote sites. They are supposed to have the same information on them, so that developers at Site 1 and Site 2 (and eventually sites 3->n) can work from the "same" repo. (Named, for the same of argument, BOB.)

Am I crazy to think that I can simply have BOB1 and BOB2 do "push" replication to each other? There's nothing in the documentation or online that indicates this should work or is a supported configuration, but I tried it and it worked. (?!)

When bringing additional sites into the loop, can we just push BOB1 -> BOB2 -> BOB3 ... BOB(n) -> BOB1?

Finally, is there an O'Reilly book or something about Artifactory that has more info than JFrog's online docs and costs less than the additional $4k they want for a support contract? I'd really like to know best practices for repository layouts and security settings.

Comment: Regarding your caveat - it's fine, Artifactory is not interned to be used only by the developers. Being an IT guy you are perfectly in the target audience.

Your understanding on the push replication is correct (both for 2 sites and for 3>n sites. It should just work. Do you have any details on what didn't work? Errors in logs? Something? Maybe you should post a screenshot of the repo configuration.

Regarding the book - currently there is none. StackExchange is a great resource for such and information, feel free to ask questions here.

Comment: There's nothing that didn't work - I just couldn't find anything in the documentation that specifically mentioned that configuration and functionality. I've seen enough other questions (on StackOverflow and elsewhere) about replication and caching that I was left a bit confused about what is and isn't supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not sure whether we are talking about a particular problem or just looking for instructions on how to do it, [here's the page on replication](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) in Artifactory User Guide. It includes both general explanations on how it works, and detailed instructions on how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** create loops in the replication architecture! The [Repository Replication page](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) warns you never to do this.

> **Avoid Replication Loops ("Cyclic Replication")**
>
> A replication loop occurs ("Cyclic" or "Bi-directional" replication) occurs when two instances of Artifactory running on different servers are replicating content from one to the other concurrently.
>
> For example, "Server A" is configured to replicate its repositories to "Server B", while at the same time, "Server B" is configured to replicate its repositories to "Server A".
>
> Or "Server A" replicates to "Server B" which replicates to "Server C" which replicates back to "Server A".
>
> We strongly recommend avoiding cyclic replication since this can have disastrous effects on your system causing loss of data, or conversely, exponential growth of disk-space usage.